# How to get video and audio streams from web cameras with Java?

Tags: java, video, audio, stream, webcam

How can I get video and audio streams from web cameras with Java (in a cross-platform way)?

For example, we have a computer with 3-4 USB web cameras; we want to get their streams and make them visible in the user interface. How can we perform such a thing? I need code for a simple app which would find ALL cameras on the computer and let us select camera to wach. Can any one, please share such one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [java media framework JMF](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/) or [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/index.php)

[Here](http://tareitas.webs.com/java/JMotionGuard/) is an example with JVM

Answer (score 4):

I see your comment about the solution needing to be "pure" java, but this is really "nearly" impossible. You will need to use some sort of native library for accessing the devices, with that being stated; I suggest that you look at Xuggler as your solution. Xuggler supports Windows, Mac, and Linux and they also offer example code for handling audio and video. Lastly the library is FREE.
Webcam capture example: http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DisplayWebcamVideo.java

While Xuggle does not have an example of microphone capture, you can find samples on the mailing list or you could use code written by the packet-mulitbroadcaster project found here: https://code.google.com/p/packet-multibroadcaster/

Comment: As a matter of fact, here's a post about capturing the screen and microphone: http://groups.google.com/group/xuggler-users/browse_thread/thread/111792482bdf1d21

Answer (score 0):

You can try [my solution](http://privateblog.by/veshhanie-s-web-kamery-cherez-websocket-realizaciya-na-java/). It uses OpenCV to capture the image and jetty server to transmit it via WebSocket. The example has three classes and it will be easy to understand.
Now I can send only video, but I'm working on audio aswell.

Comment: Improve you answer by adding some source code. Link may get broke in the future

Comment: Did you complete the audio as well

Comment: @Kanaris007 I have looked at your solution. Why do you let the client keep sending message to the WebSocket so that the WebSocket will be triggered to call `GetBase64Image();`. Does this technique not introduce unnecessary delay because the WebSocket needs to wait for message from the client in order to capture the next frame and client also needs to wait for data from the WebSocket in order to send another message to the WebSocket? Why don't you just call this method inside a while-loop  with `Thread.sleep()`, let the client send the message only one time in the `ws.onopen()` function?

Answer (score -2):

I'd use flex. It can be relatively easily integrated with java backend.

UPD:

> Pure Java needed

Then you should consider JavaFX solutions. I'm not a big expert in javafx, I've only written some basic test applications, but I'm sure it's a modern way of solving described problem with *pure java*.

Comment: bugaga...=) Yep - modern way... or you suggest to send video stream from flash to java for encoding while JAVA can handel it on its own just for fun?=)

Comment: @Ole Jak: with which part are you disagreed? You aren't agree that flash (flex) solution is counted better due to flash is simply more popular? Or don't you agree that JavaFX solution is counted better solution than solution based on applets? If you know answers then don't ask questions. -1.

Comment: 1) I do not agree to send data from flash to java because of TIME IT TAKES (you'd need to bild it in old client - server way and just keep sanding data thru http or sockets - not needed dev time spending))2) JavaFX - give an example (with source) please. 3)